# Bind a ComboBox to two DataContexts

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, wpf-controls

I have a ComboBox in my wpf application.
It's ItemsSource is binded to some table in my DataSet.
I need the text property to be binded to another's object property . I doesn't work because the ComboBox doesn't want to get two DataContexts. How can I solve this problem?

```
 <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto" MinWidth="296" Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="MyStackPanel">                      
     <ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Text={Binding Path=MyProperty} />
 </StackPanel>
```

In the code behind :

```
MyComboBox.DataContext = MyDataSet.Tables[MyTable];
MyStackPanel.DataContext = MyObject;
```

I want the ComboBox to show items from one DataContext but to show the text from another DataContext. How can I do it?

Comment: what exactly is your requirement??

Comment: @gaurawerma The items of ComboBox are from one datacontext and the the text property is binded to another DataContext - doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use DataContext. Set the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx) property of your bindings in XAML or create the [bindings in code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx) and set the Source property there.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assigning something to the datacontext of the stackpanel? From the looks of it, its not used.

Your code should work if `MyDataSet.Tables[MyTable]` returns an enumeration and contains a property called `MyProperty`.

What do you mean when you say that the combobox "doesn't want to get two DataContexts"?

Look into the properties `IsEditable` and `IsReadOnly` of the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Text={Binding ElementName=MyStackPanel Path=DataContext.MyProperty} />
```